# iOS: Detect backspace in empty UITextField with UITextField subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, subclass

The clear answer to detecting a backspace is by creating a subclass of UITextField and overriding the `deleteBackward` property.

I've created a subclass a UITextField subclass, but am getting this error:

`'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextField setMyDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

This is my subclass code:

My TextField.h:

```
@protocol MyTextFieldDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)textFieldDidDelete;
@end

@interface MyTextField : UITextField<UIKeyInput>
//create "myDelegate"
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MyTextFieldDelegate> myDelegate;
@end
```

My TextField.m:

```
- (void)deleteBackward {
    [super deleteBackward];

    if ([_myDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldDidDelete)]){
        [_myDelegate textFieldDidDelete];
    }
}
```

In my ViewController that I would like to access the UITextField subclass I do the following:

```
 #import "MyTextField.h"

 <MyTextFieldDelegate>
 @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MyTextField *passcode1;
 self.passcode1.myDelegate = self;
```

Any ideas as to why I am getting the unrecognized selector error? It looks to me like I have done everything correctly in subclassing UITextField.

Comment: sry...i missed it :P

Comment: @Mr.T any ideas as to why I am receiving the error?

Comment: do u have the method textfieldiddlete in your view controller ?

Comment: The problem appears to be with setting the delegate and has nothing to do with the deletion method.

Comment: @Mr.T I do have textFieldDidDelete in my ViewController, it is never called.  Crashes when the view loads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your outlet. The property is defined with your custom class but in a Interface Builder you added a plain old UITextField. Hence the error at runtime. In Interface Buldier, update the text field's class to be your custom class.

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue, I had created the UI before I made the subclass so I never thought to go back and make any changes in interface builder.  Good call!